# Python: What does 'and not' mean in this code

Tags: python, operators, logical-operators

This is the entire code. What does 'and not' mean in the code. I understand it to mean that only a number that will equal to 0 when the number modulus 2 is carried out.

That is if 10 is entered by the user, 2,4,6,8 will be sum to get 20.

```
the_max = int(input("Enter the upper limit:"))

the_sum = 0
extra = 0

for number in range(1,the_max):
    if number%2 and not number%3:
        the_sum = the_sum + number
    else:
        extra = extra + 1 # Line 1

print(the_sum) # Line 2
print(extra) # Line 3
```

Comment: Don't think of it as "something (and not) something else". Think of it as "(something) and (not something else)".

Answer (score 2):

It means that the `number` is not a multiple of 2 but a multiple of 3;

the if statement has two conditions:

```py
number % 2
```

since the `%` returns the remainder of a a number divided by 2, it will return 0 on a multiple of 2 and will result in rejection of if condition.

```py
and not number % 3
```

This means that we need both condition to be good. But with this one the not operand reverses it.

So this time any `number % 3` in which number is a multiple of 3 will result in 0 and will be reversed to 1;

Comment: It's not _entirely_ your fault. It's a confusing way to write it. Explicit is better than implicit, and all that.

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing it wrong. The correct interpretation is

```
if (number % 2 != 0) and (number % 3 == 0):
```

This code is taking shortcuts by omitting the explicit comparison to zero, since `0` evaluates to `False` in a boolean expression like this one, whereas any other integer value evaluates to `True`.

The second clause, thus, is given a `not` to flip its polarity. `not (number % 3)` is equivalent to `(number % 3 == 0)`.

Comment: the Boolean expression
number % 2 == 1 is the same as number % 2 . Because 1 is considered to be True for a Boolean expression. Now I understand so many things. Thank all